# Page Facebook Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a website in which displays the reviews/ratings of a facebook page through the GRAPH API using JS and JSON calls to have the ratings. But there would be no way to read these assessments without an access token, since they are public information? Or one that lives more than 60 days.

```
<script id="erasable" type="text/javascript">
    var getJSON = function(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
        `enter code here`});
    };
    getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK-PAGE-ID/ratings?access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN').then(function(data) {
        //some html pos-processing
    }, function(status) { //error detection....
        //alert('Something went wrong.');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You must use a Page access token to get ratings of a page. The API is not intended to be a mirror of the Main website so although some of the ratings will be public on the main site, they are not on the API.